# Kotlin Jsoup web scrapping

Tags: kotlin, jsoup

I'm practicing with Kotlin/Jsoup but I don't know what's wrong

Code to get:

```
                <div class="player-container">

                    <script>
                        var tabsArray = new Object();
                                                        tabsArray['1'] = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='/redirect.php?player=9&amp;code=LmdHOcKJ4LMy3D5VQ8Nk1QxqZ4wPR2ni6nL8OMtdRHY&amp;' frameborder='0' noresize scrolling='no' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
                                                </script>

                    <div class="iframe-container" id="video_player">

                    </div>
```

My code:

```
app.get(data).document.select("is-9-desktop").forEach {
            val urlDecoded = it.select("iframe").attr("src:containsOwn(redirect.php?player=9&)")
            val url2 = (urlDecoded).replace("code=", "https://www.fembed.com/v/")
            val url = (url2).substring(0,url2.indexOf("&amp;thumbnail="));
            if (url.startsWith("https://www.fembed.com")) {
                val extractor = FEmbed()
                extractor.getUrl(url).forEach { link ->
                    callback.invoke(link)
                }
```

Comment: what is the `containsOwn` thing? To me, the attr method just returns the value of the attribute. attr("src")

Comment: There are many urls and I want to get a specific one but I don't know the correct method

Comment: `containsOwn` is a css selector that target text in the element. It can't be used here. You should simply get the url with `.attr("src")` and then do something like `if (!urlDecoded.contains("redirect.php?player=9&")) return;`